# How to get a confirmation before closing the kendo modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo modal window, In which i have a form, so before closing I want to alert the user that there might be changes for that you have not saved. the problem is, kendo modal window seems to have only close event, so if I preventDefault on close event then it is difficult to close, and If I try to add custom 'X' button then it doesn't seem to be seating on the top right corner. any help/direction is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onClose(e) {
    if (e.userTriggered) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            dialog.data("kendoDialog").close();
        }
    }
}
```

Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dialog/events">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.510/styles/kendo.default-ocean-blue.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.510/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.510/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../content/shared/styles/examples-offline.css">
    <script src="../content/shared/js/console.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
    <span id="show" style="display:none" class="k-button k-button-solid-base k-button-solid k-button-md k-rounded-md hidden-on-narrow">Click here to open the dialog.</span>
    <div id="dialog"></div>

    <div class="responsive-message"></div>

    <script>
        var dialog = $("#dialog");
        var show = $("#show");

        dialog.kendoDialog({
            width: "400px",
            title: "Software Update",
            closable: true,
            modal: false,
            content: "<p>A new version of <strong>Kendo UI</strong> is available. Would you like to download and install it now?<p>",
            actions: [
                { text: 'Close', action: onClose },
                { text: 'OK', primary: true }
            ],
            close: onClose
        });
        function onClose(e) {
          if (e.userTriggered) {
              e.preventDefault();

            if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
              dialog.data("kendoDialog").close();
            }
          }
            show.fadeIn();
        }

        show.click(function () {
            dialog.data("kendoDialog").open();
            show.fadeOut();
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        #example {
            min-height: 370px;
        }

            #example .box {
                margin: 0;
            }

        #show {
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            white-space: nowrap;
            padding: 1em;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</div>

        <div class="kd-example-console">
            <div class="header">
                <span class="title">CONSOLE LOG</span>
                <span class="clear kd-text-secondary">Clear log</span>
            </div>
            <div class="console"></div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/UDEsEXoJ)